# How to Parse data from CSV File & populate UITableview in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, csv, uisearchbar

I Have a CSV File that contain 6000 rows.

I would like to Populate those 6000 rows in a TableView Then Use a SearchBar to fetch a single row

I used CSVParser but it needs 10 minutes to load the UITableview:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{

CSVParser *parser = [CSVParser sharedInstance];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [parser parseCSVFile: @"ports"];
    NSArray* rows = [dictionary allKeys];


}
```

Then to Populate the tableview:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 25;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    PortListCell *cell = (PortListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];



    cell.Codeport.text = [[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"ident"];
    cell.Nameport.text = [[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];

    NSString*CodeCountry = [[[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"iso_country"]lowercaseString];

    cell.ImageCountry.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",CodeCountry]];



    return cell;
}
```

**What is the best way to populate a UITableView with these rows ?**

Comment: You hard coded 25 rows. There is no way that took minutes to load. Perhaps parsing the CSV file took several minutes.

Comment: Yeah ! i returned the rows.count & i wanted to try just to load 25 rows...but nothing the same problem  ! Several time to load !

Comment: The issue is you're loading directly from a hard file, and there are 6000 different rows. That's a hell of a lot of information to process, and depending on whether or not the device is new or old, it will vary the time to search based on device performance. Do you need all 6000 rows? If so, I think maybe storing the CSV rows into Core Data could speed things up, but with that much information, I can't make any promises.

Comment: @SASmith My necessity is to search in the CSV file thanks to a SearchBar...but i don't know how to do it without showing all the 6000 rows in the Tableview

Comment: I would suggest to use `sqlite`, import the whole data in DB programatically once and use it, if the CSV is dynamic, you can delete all data and re-insert, it will be super fast and efficient.

Comment: @iphonic can you please put how to import the data to Sqlite programmatically. I mean the code ! Thanks

Comment: @Kingofmit I have added some code, that will give you starter for sure..

Answer (score 0):

Loading large amounts of data into table views, which will never show the whole amount of data anyway, is commonly done asynchronously, with periodic updates. If you can get into the CSV parser, perhaps it could add rows to the array and call tableview reloadData every 10 rows or something. That way your slow parsing and tableview update would happen in the background, as the table view was already appearing active to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLite` to import all the data into DB, and use it for more efficiency. I am showing you using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

The way you are parsing your data, using CSVParser you read the CSV, and insert into DB dynamically.

**You can create your insert sql query dynamically using the function below**

```
-(NSDictionary *)createInsertSQLWithValue:(NSDictionary *)value forTable:(NSString *)tableName{

    NSString *cols=@"";
    NSMutableArray *vals=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *placeHolders=@"";

    NSArray *keys=[value allKeys];

    for(NSString *key in keys){
         [vals addObject:[value objectForKey:key]];

         placeHolders=[placeHolders stringByAppendingFormat:@"?,"];

    }

    //Remove extra ","
    if(cols.length>0){
        cols=[cols substringToIndex:cols.length-1];
        placeHolders=[placeHolders substringToIndex:placeHolders.length-1];
    }

    NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@) values (%@)",tableName,cols,placeHolders];

    return @{@"sql":sql,@"args":vals};
}
```

You just need to do

```
-(void)populateData{
   CSVParser *parser = [CSVParser sharedInstance];
   NSArray *ports = [parser parseCSVFile: @"ports"];

   for(NSDictionary *value in ports){
       [self addPort:value];
   }

}

-(void)addPort:(NSDictionary*)value{
   //say you created a table ports
    NSDictionary *sql=[self createInsertSQLWithValue:value forTable:@"ports"];

    BOOL inserted=[self.db executeUpdate:[sql objectForKey:@"sql"] withArgumentsInArray:[sql objectForKey:@"args"]];
    if(inserted){
        NSLog(@"Port Inserted");
    }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you do this when you need to populate the data, if required once, do it once. And too you need to create table with the exact column name as keys in the dictionary too.

Cheers.